# How to generate specified # of sentences from a given list of words

Tags: python, nlp

I have some 100 given words, is there any available package/library in python that I can use to generate some 7-10 sentences using only these 100 words?

says words are ['Hello','is', 'time', 'you?', 'What','how', 'it?','are']

sentences will be ['Hello how are you?', ' What time is it?']

Comment: You need to build grammatically correct sentences?

Comment: yes, sentences that are meaningful /grammatically correct as much as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can train a language model (if you have training data -- some news or wikipedia articles, a book in txt format, ...), and generate sentences from that ([here](https://medium.com/swlh/language-modelling-with-nltk-20eac7e70853) is a detailed tutorial on how to dot that).

Or you can use a pretrained language model to give a score to sentences you generate randomly (a sequence of random words) and keep the ones with the highest score. The higher the score the more grammatical (according to the training corpus) the sentence will be.

Comment: Can the model pick only the given words and form sentences out of those words only ?

Comment: If your training dataset is only composed of the words you want, no. Else, there might be some way of conditioning the generation so it only outputs a defined set of words.

Comment: Thank you. also is there a way to check if the generated words are grammatically correct ?

Comment: Well if your training dataset is grammatically correct, you can check the probability of the generated sentence and if it is too small then chances are it is not very grammatical (it differs from the training data).